# connection between nolio execution server (CA-RA) and NEXUS repository

Tags: nexus, nolio

I have a question regarding implementation in secured environment: 
I have NAC and Nexus+repo in same environment and NES and agents in secured environment (over FW). NAC is connected one way to NES as stated in documentation
Is there an need to Open a connection between the NES and the NEXUS repo ? 
or not ? I did not find any documentation on that ...

What are the best practices to deploy to agents over FW ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the list of ports for communication between NAC, NES and other tools for Nolio environment. Those ports should be open for communication, by adding an exception in your firewall rules.

Answer (score 1):

The NES doesn't need to communicate with the nexus repository (Its main job is to serve as a proxy between the NAC and the agents)

Note:

- The NAC connects to the repository to sync its action packs and store manifests
- Agents that serve as artifact retrieval agents for artifacts that are set to be stored in the internal repository, need to be able to connect to the repository

I'm not sure what is FW

Answer (score 0):

In our project we create a artifact type under artifact management and define it as zip/tar. Now if you can access the artifact over HTTP, that can be provided as the artifact definition. There is also an option to download the artifact and save in Nolio if you check the check box.